# X Range chart label inside is not visible if x axis value is too small

Tags: highcharts

I am using X Range Highcharts.
If the x axis values are too small and the chart is very small, then the label inside is not visible properly. Also i am able to apply ellipsis for it.

Is there a possibility for this?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the output you are seeing?

Comment: Hi @Sarwan, As you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qywfx7j5/ every data label is visible. Could you adapt the example to show the problem?